# Libgdx Screens are not swapping

Tags: java, screen, libgdx

I am new to Libgdx and I was wrote a class that extends the Game class, the thing is that the setScreen() method from Game is not swapping the screens because after I set the screen my game still renders only what is in the render method from the game class and not what is in the render method of screen class. This is the code:

If a run this code I only get a red screen even though I change screens when the user touches(clicks) the screen

```
class myGame extends Game
{
    GameScreen myOtherScreen;

    public void create() 
    {
       //create other screen
       myMenuScreen = new GameScreen();
    }

    public void render(float delta) 
    {   
        // change screens if screen touched
        if(Gdx.input.justTouched())
            setScreen(myOtherScreen);

            //render red screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    }
    .
    . //other methods
    .
}

// ======= Screen Class ========

public class GameScreen implements Screen
{
     @Override
     public void render(float delta) 
     {
            //render green screen
         Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
         Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);      
     }
     .
     . //other methods
     .
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You aren't using the game class properly. You shouldn't do any rendering there, that's the screens' task.

You should check out the [libgdx screen and game classes wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses). 
The usage should be somewhere like this:

```
public class MyGame extends Game {
        @Override
        public void create() {
                setScreen(new RedScreen(this));              
        }
 }
```

and have a RedScreen like this:

```
public class RedScreen implements Screen {
    MyGame game; 
    public RedScreen(MyGame game){
            this.game = game;
    }

    public void render(float delta) {
        if(Gdx.input.justTouched())
            game.setScreen(new GreenScreen(game);

         //render red screen
         Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
         Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
    // ... more screen functions
}
```

and have a GreenScreen like this:

```
public class GreenScreen implements Screen {
    MyGame game; 
    public MainMenuScreen(MyGame game){
            this.game = game;
    }

    public void render(float delta) {
         //render green screen
         Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
         Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
    // ... more screen functions
}
```

Answer (score 5):

found the problem the solution is not to use the render method from the game class in fact you actually HAVE TO DELETE IT from the class believe me you have to do all the render in the other screen classes.

Answer (score 3):

I found the root cause. Actually, you must add `super.render()` in your Game's `render()` method before you draw other things in Game. If not, the render method you overrided will not call the Screen's `render()` method.

BTW: The best practice is rendering things using class Screen.

Notice that: Even an empty `render()` in Game will causes this issue. So, delete `render()` in your Game or add `super.render()` in it.